# Is the IBM JRE a Standard VM?

Tags: eclipse, jvm, virtual-machine, java

I'm adding a JRE to Eclipse and I was given 3 options:

- Execution Environment Description
- Standard 1.1.x VM
- Standard VM

I was wondering if:

1. All JREs end up being VMs?
2. Does VM in this case mean JVM?
3. If the IBM JRE specifically was a Standard VM?
4. How do the 3 choices relate to each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

VM here refers to JVM. Any implementation of a JRE or JDK contains a Java Virtual Machine. The IBM implementation is, as far as I know, fully compatible with the Java specification, so you don't need to worry about compatibility. The distribution's name probably includes what version of the Java spec it's compatible with.

The options you were given allow you to choose between a JVM compatible with the 1.1.X version of Java, or one compatible with a later version (the latest is 7, but support for 6 is pretty wide as well). Unless you're maintaining some ancient legacy code, you'll want to add a "Standard VM" to your IDE.

Comment: "Any implementation of a JRE or JDK contains a Java Virtual Machine." So, does the JDK include it's own JRE? or is the JRE part of the JDK? When using the IBM JRE, am I specifying the JDK I want, but asking Eclipse to use a different JRE than what is included with the JDK?

Comment: A JDK ("Java Development Kit") always includes a JRE ("Java Runtime Environment"). You can look inside the JDK's installation directory and find a "jre" directory in there, in fact. The JDK adds source files, documentation, and other stuff on top of what you get from a JRE. 

If you installed a JRE separately from your JDK, and specify the former in Eclipse, then yes, you might be using a different JRE than the one in your JDK. If they're both from IBM then it's the same as using your included JRE, but I personally prefer to use the one from the JDK when possible.